# Showing an Ideal is finitely generated in $\mathbb R[x,y]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I found a problem on an old exam from an abstract algebra course. This was one of the problems I did not have a solution too.

Let $A$ and $B$ be a pair of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ that commute; that is, $AB = BA$. Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}[x, y]$
be the set of relations between $A$ and $B$; that is, polynomials $f(x, y)$ such that $f(A, B)$ is the zero matrix. Prove that $I$ is a finitely generated ideal in $\mathbb R[x, y]$.

My first attempt has been to try and find a set of generators, this failed and I'm out of ideas.  It has been some time since taking the course, so I don't recall if there are any relevant results to use on this problem.  I've not considered ideals since taking this course, but I would like a solution to this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Where $R$ is...?

Comment: Do you really want $R$ to be $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the real numbers? If that's the case, then this is true because *every* ideal of $\mathbb{R}[X, Y]$ is finitely generated by Hilbert's basis theorem.

Comment: I do really want R to be \mathb{R} simply because the problem states it that way.  Thank you for the suggestion.  I will be sure to look at Hilbert's basis theorem.